# Why is my file descriptor to a bluetooth socket null?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

Can someone please help me figure out why I can only get a null file descriptor to a Bluetooth socket opened via BluetoothServerSocket.accept()?

My goal is streaming video between two devices over bluetooth, by writing video to a file descriptor on one side and reading it from a file descriptor on the other side.  My Bluetooth connection is good, I can send raw data back and forth, but I can only get a file descriptor on the client side.  On the server side, using the same code, I can only get a null file descriptor.  In the debugger I can see a file descriptor on the server side at **mySocket.mSocketIS.this$0.fd**, but I can't figure out how to get access to it.  Can anyone help?  This is Android 4.4.2, here's my code:

First the broken code (Server side):

```
    // Listen for an incoming Bluetooth connection
class AcceptThread extends Thread
{
    // Thread that accepts incoming bluetooth connections
    public AcceptThread()
    {
        try
        {
            // Open a listening server socket.  This is non-blocking
            btServerSocket = BA.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("ServerApp", videoUUID);
        } catch(IOException e){ btServerSocket = null; }
    } // AcceptThread()

    public void run()
    {
        BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;

        // Listen until exception or we have a socket
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                // Blocking call to accept an incoming connection.  To get out of this, call cancel() which closes the socket, causing .accept() to throw an exception
                btSocket = btServerSocket.accept();
                // If we get here, we're connected!  

                Field pfdField = btSocket.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPfd");
                pfdField.setAccessible(true);
                ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = (ParcelFileDescriptor) pfdField.get(btSocket);

                // >>> ERROR - pfd is null  <<<<   I can see a fd at mySocket.mSocketIS.this$0.fd;, but how do I access it? 


                FileDescriptor myFd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();  


              // ... blah blah...
```

Now the working code (Client side):

```
    // Connect to a remote device as the client (we are the client)
class ConnectThread extends Thread
{
    // ctor
    // remoteUUID - The UUID of the remote device that we want to connect to
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice btDevice, UUID remoteUUID)
    {
        // Get a BT socket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try
        {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            btClientSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(remoteUUID);
        }catch(Exception e){ postUIMessage("ConnectThread exception: " + e.toString());    }
    } // ConnectThread ctor

    public void run()
    {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        BA.cancelDiscovery();
        try
        {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block until it succeeds or throws an exception.  To get out, call cancel() below, which will cause .connect() to throw an exception.
            btClientSocket.connect();

            Field pfdField = btClientSocket.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPfd");
            pfdField.setAccessible(true);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = (ParcelFileDescriptor) pfdField.get(btClientSocket);
            FileDescriptor myFd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();  // Pass this to Recorder.setOutputFile();

            // Yay myFd is good!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix on my side regarding this issue, we are using bluetooth as a server too. I found the file descriptor from the LocalSocket field in BluetoothSocket. My goal was to get teh file and close it.

```
int mfd = 0;
        Field socketField = null;
        LocalSocket mSocket = null;

        try
        {
            socketField = btSocket.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSocket");
            socketField.setAccessible(true);

            mSocket = (LocalSocket)socketField.get(btSocket);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log ( "Exception getting mSocket in cleanCloseFix(): " + e.toString());
        }

        if(mSocket != null)
        {
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor =
                    mSocket.getFileDescriptor();

            String in = fileDescriptor.toString();

            //regular expression to get filedescriptor index id
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

            while(m.find()) {
                Log ( "File Descriptor " + m.group(1));
                mfd = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
                break;
            }

            //Shutdown the socket properly
            mSocket.shutdownInput();
            mSocket.shutdownOutput();
            mSocket.close();

            mSocket = null;

            try { socketField.set(btSocket, mSocket); }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log ("Exception setting mSocket = null in cleanCloseFix(): " + e.toString());
            }

            //Close the file descriptor when we have it from the Local Socket
            try {
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.adoptFd(mfd);
                if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
                    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                    Log ( "File descriptor close succeed : FD = " + mfd);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log ( "File descriptor close exception " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I will try this when I'm back on the project.